# 'value' is declared but its value is never read.ts(6133)

Tags: reactjs

```
const Rating = ( { value , text}) => {
    return (
        <div className='rating'>
            <span>
                <i className={ value => 1 ? 'fas fa-star' :value=>0.5?'fas fa-star-half-alt' : 'far fa-star'}></i>
            </span>
            <span>
                <i className={value =>2 ? 'fas fa-star' :value=>1.5?'fas fa-star-half-alt' : 'far fa-star'}></i>
            </span>
            <span>
                <i className={value=>3? 'fas fa-star' :value=>2.5?'fas fa-star-half-alt' : 'far fa-star'}></i>
            </span>
            <span>
                <i className={value => 4? 'fas fa-star' :value=>3.5?'fas fa-star-half-alt' : 'far fa-star'}></i>
            </span>
            <span>
                <i className={value => 5? 'fas fa-star' :value=>4.5?'fas fa-star-half-alt' : 'far fa-star'}></i>
            </span>
            <span>{text&& text}</span>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: can you elaborate the question?

Comment: I'll find the dupetarget, but basically you've created an arrow function rather than doing a comparison. Use `>=`, not `=>`. `value => 1 ? x : y` creates a function accepting a `value` parameter and returning the result of `1 ? x : y` (which is the value of `x`). You want `value >= 1 ? x : y`.

Comment: Better yet, extract the duplicate logic out and make this more pleasant to read :)

Answer (score 0):

I think the solution is simple, you are not using correctly the ***greater than or equal*** operator. `>=` is not equal `=>`

```
<span>
  <i className={ value >= 1 ? 'fas fa-star' :value >=0.5?'fas fa-star-half-alt' : 'far fa-star'}></i>
</span>
```

I think it should work.
To know more about operators, you can find it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators#relational_operators)

Comment: In general, for JS docs, it's better to link to something like the [MDN Relational Operators overview docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators#relational_operators) than to w3schools. Plus there's an explicit note regarding `=>`.